# Empty application group in program overview can't be deleted

Tags: menu

I uninstalled 3 apps that I had placed into a 'group' in the Ubuntu 22.04 menus. The empty group remains but can't be removed in any obvious way.

It needs to go. How can I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the norm, I've solved it, myself.

Reinstall the apps. Drag them out of the group. The group disappears. Uninstall the apps again.

There is obviously a bug in Gnome or Ubuntu that doesn't handle all the apps in a menu grouping being uninstalled. I imagine the devs didn't thinks about that case occurring.